# Google Feed API Giving Wrong Result

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I have used FEED Api and my RSS is http://219.64.5.9/androidwebservice/rssfeed.aspx?linkname=Demo but when i am checking it on

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=feeds#load_feed  with the URL entered i am getting only one feed . Please your help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide), you have to specify the number of entries to load (with a maximum of 250). You could also use `.includeHistoricalEntries()` to add feed entries stored by Google that are no longer in the feed XML.

However, upon clicking your feeds, I only see three entries on it. Maybe you need to fix it first.